# How could you implement a staggered row layout in Android?

Tags: android, listview

How would you implement a layout with multiple columns, where the rows of each column don't line up? I'm thinking of something like:

```
----------
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
|--|  |  |
|  |--|  |
|--|  |--|
|  |--|  |

...
```

And so on. An example of something like this is a website like Pinterest.

I'm looking for best practices here from experienced Android devs. Does it make sense to use multiple ListViews and keep them in sync somehow? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a new development going on for `StaggeredGridView`, see this project: https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView
(via [androidviews.net](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/)). It's pretty much like the Pinterest app layout.

Comment: Nice, this looks like it can be a solution so I'll go ahead and accept this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `GridLayout`,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

and put that inside of a `ScrollView`,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Isn't a Gridview on a grid? How would you do the staggered layout with a grid? None of the elements are of a uniform height, so they may never line up. I'm also concerned about memory usage if I use a scrollview -- doesn't this mean that all the views would be loaded in memory? I don't really want to implement my own custom layout engine.